# querySelect angular component as MyComponent

Tags: jquery-selectors, dart, components, angular-dart

I have an angular component

```dart
<my-component foo="" bar=""></my-component>
```

And its corresponding class **MyComponent**

I use this component in my html

```dart
<my-component foo="bar" bar="foo"></my-component>
<my-component foo="baz" bar="qux"></my-component>
<my-component foo="bar" bar="baz"></my-component>
```

Now i want to querySelect my custom elements and access their attributes directly. I think about something like this:

```dart
List<MyComponent> mys = querySelector('my-component');

mys.forEach((my){
  print(my.foo);
  my.bar = '1234';
});
```

There are a view problems with that code:

1. querySelector always returns **Element** not **MyComponent**. can i cast Element to MyComponent?
2. Is MyComponent to <my-component> like DivElement to <div>?
3. querySelector cannot select custom elements. i could ad a class to every my-component and select it with that class. or is there another way?
4. I only can access the attributes with my.getAttribute() not with my.foo. I know, this is because my is still a Element not a MyComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not officially supported. There was something like `ng-element` that allowed this as far as I remember but was intended to be only used for unit tests. There were some changes in the last versions but I don't know the current state.

You should pass references using dependency injection, Angular events (explained here [How to communicate between Angular DART controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151427)) or the scope to access other elements.

Comment: I solved it with emit/broadcast like in my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26176002/1310337 Now my components don't know about each other and only communicate over events. That's much simpler and cleaner than selecting the components.