# DI - No provider found for EventBus

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

Using Angular Dart, I define an event bus like this:

```dart
class MyModule extends Module {

    MyModule() {
        bind(EventBus, toImplementation: EventBus);
        ...
    }
}
```

When I want to inject this event bus into a component by simply doing:

```dart
class MyComponent {

    final EventBus _eventBus;

    MyComponent(this._eventBus) {}
}
```

I am getting the error:

```dart
No provider found for EventBus!
```

I have no idea how to debug this...

The event bus is an external library, which looks like:

```dart
library event_bus;

import 'dart:async';

@MirrorsUsed(symbols: '*') // Do not keep any names.
import 'dart:mirrors';

class EventBus {

  StreamController _streamController;

  EventBus({bool sync: false}) {
    _streamController = new StreamController.broadcast(sync: sync);
  }
  ...
}
```

Any help welcome... thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want this? Angular.dart has an event bus built in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151427. You need to install the module somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but in this case - when you can't put easily an @Injectable() annotation on the class - the simplest solution is to give the injector a value :

```dart
bind(EventBus, toValue: new EventBus());
```

Comment: Probably the better way because you probably want the same instance every time. `toImplementation` would create a new instance. On the other side Angular has something like EventBus build-in. Do you really need a custom event bus...